# Can i create an API endpoint from nodejs and nextjs web application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js, chatgpt-api

I have found online repo that uses Pinecone, GPT 3.5 and create vectors from PDFs, it transform those vectors and store them on pinecone, then the user access this app and then ask questions to chatGPT and it response from that PDFs files.
Here is the Repo [link](https://github.com/mayooear/gpt4-pdf-chatbot-langchain)

**NOTE**: go to multiple PDFs brnach

I have no experiance in NodeJs or javascript and i need to create an API from this application to recive the PDFs from the API user and store them in the docs folder as shown in the repo multiple pdfs branch, and the other endpoint of the API is the chatting it self that will be created, is that possible ?

I have tried to make the full application in FastAPI or in Flask but it took too much time and the result wasn't good, i have found this repo that saved me lots of time but it missing the API.

Comment: Yes un the surface all those things sound possible.

Comment: I made the API after studying javascript and with the help of GPT4, however, I need to modify one thing which is when ever the response is created it is generated as chunks to be shown to the user frontend as the bot is typing text, it makes a problem while sending those data into the API request and I had to handle he incoming data with "re" library in python (i have made the request example in python), do you have any solution for that or to point to the section that creating those chunks? @Evert

Comment: If you have a specific question, open a new question here and share your problem + the code you tried + any error messages you got.